# No DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were recived

Tags: networking, 18.04, dhcp, interface, ltsp-client

I'm trying to install a server for multiple machines, already did the main steps, but when I try to turn on a machine, it keeps loading DHCP and then shows the error below.

What seems to be the problem?

[image: error]

Comment: Please let us know if you discovered what the problem was and if my answer helped you. If you still need any assistance, share with us what have you tried so far and the results.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't fully specified your installation method and BIOS configurations, so I'll address both messages:

If you are trying to install a system using a [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) server, it seems like your machine fails to receive an IP address while performing the  DHCP [DORA](https://ipwithease.com/understanding-dora-process-in-dhcp/) step.
Your network adapter seems to work properly, as the boot agent loads and recognizes a L2 link to your next device (a switch for example).

What may cause a DORA failure?

- No DHCP servers are available
- DHCP server is unreachable (when on the same LAN).
- No DHCP relay is available to route your Discovery request from your broadcast domain to your DHCP LAN (if your machine is not in the same LAN with the server).
- A firewall or any other device intercepts your Discovery requests.
- Your DHCP chooses to ignore your Discovery requests (for example: it uses a service "allow list" based on MAC address).
- Wrong NIC chosen (for machines with multiple NICs).

The last error message (DISK BOOT FAILURE) means that after failing your first set boot option (a PXE boot), it moves to the next boot option which is set to be a bootable hard drive and fails to find one.